# How to derive types from strings in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object which I need to derive types from, see obj:

```
const obj = {
  PROP1: {
    type: 'number',
  },
  PROP2: {
    type: 'string',
  },
  PROP3: {
    type: 'boolean',
  },
  PROP4: {
    type: 'string',
  },
}
```

Which I now would wish to transform to type like:

```
type ObjType = {
  PROP1: number;
  PROP2: string;
  PROP3: boolean;
  PROP4: string;
};
```

All my solutions have failed and its something I really would like to achieve so help is always appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to create your own mapping from names like `"string"` to types like `string` before you could do any kind of programmatic transformation; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaLZyw) for an example.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz the solution does not appear to solve my problem, when I implemented, I seem to have lost the types all together

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue you're having; what specifically did you implement?  Did you remember to use `as const` with `obj`?

Comment: @jcalz have a look at this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDcEMBsFcFMB0AXAzgKAMYHsB2rlRsAjAK1AF5QBvdUUABQCUB5BgRgC4a77RkAngAd43AOS5YAW2LwATmIA0vAL7L6zNgCZutPv2GjQYgnICWuAOZLV6xqwYBmXb3qCR44tmzR4kXDb0aryaDAAsLvruRibI5laBoMEqANzo8AAeQthyhAAm8ABmkLDQhCSkaeggBiKoKBg1AO4AFpCEAJL85vB5oKjYoMVyoK1mmC2gbaiguNiETTkA1r3o1WBmUtm5RGRDcthSxojAUHDwYlXRoACiuOAMB0IAKoYAgnKWADwMoJnI8FweRmpgslgAfJRGH8MgCgTNYvFrKAAPz9OJg0DcSQyeRXQy3e4sMhfZ6Qqh6UAAbQA0qALKAVgJsIVQM8ALrcZ609kwuHAmi1IwWQryUAAVT5gIFoKsSVRhIeT1eIg+33FkOx8HAePQqTW12JpBV8Chd3ARq+0RZu1I4KAA)

Comment: So you didn't use `as const` with `obj`.  When you do that [it works as I showed](https://tsplay.dev/WzBQRW).  Is there a reason you can't use `as const` here?  Or was it just an oversight when you tried to implement my suggestion?  How should we proceed here?

Comment: It was an oversight, that worked, thanks alot, you can put in answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to possibly work you need to change `obj` so that the compiler keeps track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `type` subproperties.  Otherwise the compiler will just assume that they are all `string`; that's a reasonable assumption in general, since people often want to change the values of string properties, but it throws away the information you care about.

The easiest way to ask the compiler to track the literal types of things in an object literal is to use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const obj = {
  PROP1: {
    type: 'number',
  },
  PROP2: {
    type: 'string',
  },
  PROP3: {
    type: 'boolean',
  },
  PROP4: {
    type: 'string',
  },
} as const;
```

Now we can proceed.

---

You'll need to make your own mapping from names of types to actual types; there's no built-in functionality like this in TypeScript:

```
interface TypeMap {
  number: number;
  string: string;
  boolean: boolean;
  // add other names you care about
}
```

Once you do that you can write a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to iterate over the properties in `typeof obj` and convert them as desired:

```
type ObjType = { -readonly [K in keyof typeof obj]: TypeMap[typeof obj[K]["type"]] }
/* type ObjType = {
    PROP1: number;
    PROP2: string;
    PROP3: boolean;
    PROP4: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAFASgPK4CMAXBtjjFAJ4AOAphQORgCuAtvIwE4sAaKgF8hOAsQBMFLNRoNmMFtF4BLMAHNBIsXiK4AzDKo46TVvBAgANowCGYbTlFUJuACzG5ZxcqhrNJxgXYRg7CBhQSCgAbkx49Sg+ADM7YEYYABUFAFk7ekocDm4+CmKeXjicFXUNChrNKphLG3swChbbByaAeh6wgBMBuCgACz4YMDtORgjaEHZIu14Mu0t2KExheJ8YQiRsplQMGABaFbsB8GtaGABtAGkYdRgAa0Z55PkmEC+ERAAuhRDow8vQ7j5fnAkI8AXcAEQ+eEAgHBTA9ABU3wy+0QIOOsmobnIky4FSa4n00hgDQ0FL0xCMzSsXTA9Lcnhp-lqcVCGJ6QA)